# Calculate Mean for Parts of time Series

Tags: r, time-series, mean

I have a data Frame of annual values that Looks something like this:

```
Time             Value
01/2000-12/2000   123
01/2001-12/2001   126
01/2002-12/2002   129
...
01/2040-12/2040   223
```

I would like to Calculate the mean for certain parts of the time series (e.g. 2010-2015; 2015-2020; etc.)

Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Not a reproducible example . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# first extract the year
df$year <- as.numeric(sub(".*\\/", "", df$Time))
# then a simple mean() does the work for you!
mean(df$Value[df$year >= 2000 & df$year <= 2005])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do sth like this if your column `Time` is in `Date` format:

To transfer the column into date format use:

```
my.data.frame$Date = as.Date(paste("01.01.",sub(".*\\/", "", my.data.frame$Time),sep = ""),format = "%d.%m.%Y")
```

Then to calculate the mean:

```
mean(my.data.frame[my.data.frame$Date >= "2016-01-01" & my.data.frame$Date <= "2020-01-01","Value"])
```

Comment: the data doesn't have time in the format you expect it to be!

Comment: I added some code.